# How to use syslog to log some message on terminal?

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, syslog

I have to use syslog to log a message on terminal.
I found a code on internet but it is not working.
code:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <unistd.h>
 #include <syslog.h>

int main(void) 
{    
openlog("slog", LOG_PID|LOG_CONS, LOG_USER);  
syslog(LOG_INFO, "A different kind of Hello world ... ");
closelog();  
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't just assume that LOG_CONS does what you want it to do. Read the documentation for the syslog function. The LOG_PERROR flag is more like what you want to do.

Comment: Look at [printk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printk) settings.

Comment: @Ipor, what does `printk` have to do with user-mode programs?

Comment: It can be configured which type of syslog messages will go to the terminal. You can disable it completely and enable more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to all for comments and answers.

Now, I am able to print a message on the terminal by using LOG_PERROR option in openlog() function.There is no need of LOG_CONS option to print on console.
Thanks to @Cheatah for the help.
openlog("slog", LOG_PID|LOG_PERROR, LOG_USER);

Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

This should work: `openlog("slog", LOG_PID|LOG_CONS, LOG_DAEMON);`

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer, get 3 more rep and you'll be able to comment. Not (yet) downvoted.

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.